# Mongoose virtual field not updated

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i created a schema for user like this:

```
    var schema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    hashedPassword: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    salt: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

schema.virtual('password')
    .set(function(password) {
        this._plainPassword = password;
        this.salt = Math.random() + '';
        this.hashedPassword = this.encryptPassword(password);
    })
    .get(function() { return this._plainPassword; });

schema.methods.encryptPassword = function(password) {
    return crypto.createHmac('sha1', this.salt).update(password).digest('hex');
};
```

then I'm trying to change the password using the two approaches:

1. work nice

   User.findById('userId..', function(err, user) {
       user.password = '456';
       user.save(cb);
       })
2. why is this approach not working ?

   User.findByIdAndUpdate('userId', {$set: {password: '456'}}, cb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because Mongoose doesn't apply any of the following on a `findByIdAndUpdate()` operation:

- defaults
- setters
- validators
- middleware

From the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate):

> If you need those features, use the traditional approach of first
>   retrieving the document.
>
> ```
> Model.findById(id, function (err, doc) {
>   if (err) ..
>   doc.name = 'jason borne';
>   doc.save(callback);
> })
> ```

Answer (score 0):

with version 4.0.9+ middleware supports `findByIdAndUpdate()`.

```
CustomerSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next, done) {
   console.log("findOneAndUpdate pre middleware!!!");
   next();
});
```